# Incorrect results via Nexpose, but displaying correct one with Nmap

Tags: penetration-test, network-scanners

We are scanning our network via Nexpose. Recently an asset was found vulnerable to Wannacry CVE 2017-0146 SMB Remote code execution vulnerability. However when i have tested it same through Nmap it doesn't show me any vulnerability. I have used following command: nmap -p 445 --script vuln . It gives me following result:

samba-vuln-cve-2012-1182: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

|_smb-vuln-ms10-054: false

|_smb-vuln-ms10-061: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

Is Nexpose showing false positive related to this particular target. I know we can verify same with metasploit as well, but we are not authorized to use it in our organisation. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

We can’t answer this with much certainty without knowing your system. But have you checked the Windows version of the system being flagged? The CVE [details affected versions](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-0146). And anyway these are all quite old versions of Windows - I’d imagine you should want to patch them anyway for the sake of future security updates as well.

Separately you also might want to examine your vuln scanning pipeline if it’s giving a lot of false positives. But we all know how vuln scanning is, and how that might be easier said than done. ;)